# Is boost::managed_shared_memory using a file on my hard drive?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

When I create a new `boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory`, I can see a file appear in `C:\ProgramData\boost_interprocess\1571641094\NAME_OF_SHARED_MEMORY` which size seems to match that of the shared memory created.

My understanding from the [documention](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html) is that there are two widely used objects usable to share memory between processes (within  `managed_shared_memory`'s scope):

- **basic_managed_shared_memory**
- **basic_managed_mapped_file**

The `managed_shared_memory` uses the `basic_managed_shared_memory` implementation. I assumed this implementation is proper *shared **memory*** and not a *memory mapped **file***.

Seeing that it uses a file puzzles me. Are both of these managed shared memory based on a memory mapped file implementation ?

Is the only boost shared memory solution on Windows that avoids memory mapped files the `windows_shared_memory` ?

NB : I am on Windows 10, using VC++ on VS2013.

Code sample that can reproduce the behaviour of creating a file in `ProgramData` when using a `managed_shared_memory` :

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  boost::interprocess::permissions permissions;
  permissions.set_unrestricted();

  boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory* sharedMemory;
  sharedMemory = new boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory(
  {
    boost::interprocess::open_or_create,
    "NAME_OF_SHARED_MEMORY",
    400000,
    0,
    permissions
  }
  );

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. The '[Emulation for systems without shared memory objects](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.emulation)' section from the Boost documentation explains what is going on:

> Boost.Interprocess provides portable shared memory in terms of POSIX
>   semantics. Some operating systems don't support shared memory as
>   defined by POSIX:
>
> - Windows operating systems provide shared memory using memory backed by the paging file but the lifetime semantics are different
>     from the ones defined by POSIX (see Native windows shared memory
>     section for more information).
>
> ...
>
> In those platforms, shared memory is emulated with mapped files
>   created in a "boost_interprocess" folder created in a temporary files
>   directory. In Windows platforms, if "Common AppData" key is present in
>   the registry, "boost_interprocess" folder is created in that directory
>   (in XP usually "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data"
>   and in Vista "C:\ProgramData"). For Windows platforms without that
>   registry key and Unix systems, shared memory is created in the system
>   temporary files directory ("/tmp" or similar).
>
> Because of this emulation, shared memory has filesystem lifetime in
>   some of those systems.

As you already pointed out, as an alternative, you can use [native windows shared memory](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.windows_shared_memory) objects (using [`windows_shared_memory`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.html)). It will use a shared memory object backed by the pagefile instead of a file being created in `C:\ProgramData`. In general, this will not use the filesystem (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215317/79111). In case portability is not a concern, it is probably a better approach since it allows interoperability with other applications that use shared memory but do not rely on Boost.Interprocess.

Comment: About the last paragraph, in the normal case it will *not* hit the disk; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6215317/214671

Comment: @MatteoItalia, thanks I've corrected the paragraph.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel Thanks a lot ! That answers a lot of my questions. Out of curiosity, does the fact that we are using the filesystem mean that it is safe to assume data stored in a `manged_shared_memory` will still be there after a reboot since it is based on the filesystem ? Or is it not a supported behaviour and considered temp data that can and will be wiped eventually by the OS ?

Comment: @Norgannon, no, you cannot make that assumption. The shared memory block is automatically destroyed as soon as no processes are attached to it anymore. Windows will take care of that for you. This is actually convenient, under POSIX, you will have to clean up the shared-memory file manually, which can become tricky in certain corner cases. You can still get persistence across reboots of course, but you will you will have to write out the data to file yourself at some point before your process stops.

Comment: Alright, understood ! Again, thanks a lot for all these informations :D